# how to replace non integer value on a starting of a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe,

```
 df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2],"B":["a 1",np.nan]})

    A   B
0   1   a 1
1   2   NaN
```

I am trying to replace the `df.B` values to the integer values in it.
(i.e) if we have `abcd.. 1` i want to convert it to 1.

I tried,

```
df.B.replace(np.nan,"").astype(str).str.replace('^[^\d]*', '').astype(int)
```

but it is not converting the empty string. I am getting 
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` Please help to achieve my output. Thanks in advance.

My expected output is,

```
     A   B
 0   1   1
 1   2   ''
```

Comment: How do you expect to have an `int` column with an empty `string` value? Is there a reason it cannot be `NaN`? If the column can be `object` type then: `df.B = df.B.astype(str).str.replace('^[^\d]*', '')`, but `1` will be a `string`.

Comment: if it s a numerical value after `replace('^[^\d]*', '')` we can convert it to int, else I want just `''`

Answer (score 3):

If want extract `integer`s and for all another values get same values use custom function with `try-except`:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x

df.B = df.B.replace('^[^\d]*', '', regex=True).fillna('').apply(f)
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  

print (df.B.apply(type))
0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'str'>
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether column B will contain something like `"X"` where no digits are in it so I tried with `pd.to_numeric` in the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2, 3],"B":["a 1",np.nan, "X"]})
df["B"]= pd.to_numeric(
             df.B.str.extract("(\d+)"), errors="ignore"
         ).fillna("")
    A   B
0   1   1
1   2   
2   3
```

Thanks jezrael for noticing my mistakes.

Comment: there is no integer, test it by `print (df.B.apply(type))`

Comment: @jezrael ohhh I started with OP's df that contains `str`. updated!

Comment: Same problem, test it ;)